# copy the value of the variable rather than reference bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I am a bit new to the bash scripting. So please bear with me. I am trying to create a table and assign the values in for loop like this:

```
packages=("foo" "bar" "foobar")
packageMap=()
function test() {
    i=0;
    for package in "${packages[@]}"
    do
        echo $i
        packageMap[$package]=$i
        i=$(expr $i + 1)
    done
}

test
echo the first value is ${packageMap["foo"]}
```

The output for this is:

```
0
1
2
the first value is 2
```

While my expected output is:

```
0
1
2
the first value is 0
```

So basically the variable's reference is being assigned to this rather than the value. How to solve this?

My bash version:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
```

TIA

Comment: BTW, `i=$(( i + 1 ))` is **much** more efficient than `i=$(expr $i + 1)`, as `$( )` needs to fork off a child process, and `expr` is implemented with an external command -- `/bin/expr` -- not part of the shell. The `$(( ))` form has been present in the POSIX sh standard since its initial publication in 1991, so there's also no concern about portability.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : Apart of POSIX compatibility, is there an advantage of using `i=$(( i + 1 ))` over `((i++))`? I find the latter easier to read and to type.

Comment: @user1934428, see [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) -- `((i++))` can (depending on the interpreter version) cause your script to exit when you're using `set -e`. `((++i))` is less prone to that issue (would only happen when `i` is initially negative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As chep says, there are no associative arrays in bash 3.  That said, if you don't mind wasting a bit of CPU, you can use functions to similar effect:

```
#!/bin/bash

packages=("foo" "bar" "foobar")

function packagemap () {
    local i
    for i in "${!packages[@]}"; do
        [[ ${packages[$i]} = $1 ]] && echo "$i" && return
    done
    echo "unknown"
}

echo "the first value is $(packagemap "foo")"
```

The `${!array[@]}` construct expands to the set of indices for the array, which for a normally non-associative array consist of incrementing integers starting at 0. But array members can be removed without the indices being renumbered (i.e. `unset packages[1]`), so it's important to be able to refer to *actual* indices rather than assuming they're sequential with for loop that simply counts.

And I note that you're using Darwin. Remember that you really need it, you can install bash 4 using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

Comment: Yes, I dont mind using up a bit of cpu since this script is for triggering the build command for my gradle packages. Since I cant install bash 4 on the machine I am using, I can only go in this way. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 6):

`bash` 3.2 only has indexed arrays, so `packageMap[$package]` only works as intended if `$package` is an integer, not an arbitrary string.

(What you are observing is `$package` being evaluated in an arithmetic context, where `foo`, `bar`, and `foobar` are recursively expanded until you get an integer value. Undefined variables expand to 0, so `packageMap[foo]` is equivalent to `packageMap[0]`.)

If you were using `bash` 4 or later, you could use an associative array:

```
packages=("foo" "bar" "foobar")
declare -A packageMap
test () {
    i=0
    for package in "${packages[@]}"
    do
        echo $i
        packageMap[$package]=$i
        i=$(($i + 1))
    done
}
```

Given that `i` is the same as the index of each element of `packages`, you could also write

```
test () {
    for i in "${!packages[@]}"; do
        package=${packages[i]}
        packageMap[$package]=$i
    done
}
```

instead of explicitly incrementing `i`.

Comment: could you change `i=$(($i+1))` to `((i++))` so that psykid learns the shortcut?

Comment: @jeremysprofile Better to suggest `(( ++i ))` so it doesn't trigger failures with `set -e` on first invocation (as the postincrement will evaluate to the initial value, and `(( 0 ))` is falsey). See the first exercise in [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) (granted, *some* versions of bash exempt arithmetic results from `set -e` behavior, but relying on that is creating a nonobvious version dependency).

Comment: @chepner, I tried to use this in bash 3.2 (before posting here), of course it didn't work. Unfortunately I cant install bash 4 since I don't have admin rights on that machine.

Comment: You don't need admin rights; you can install anything you want in your own home directory.